# hide server side data in modal dialog

Tags: php, javascript, modal-dialog

I am trying to retrieve some data from server side and then display it using a modal dialog.

here is my dialog box div

```
<div id="dialog1" title="Some title">
    <?php                   
        echo "Data to display within modal dialog box"; 
    ?>
</div>
```

And here is my JS script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button1").click(function(){     //button1 is the id for a button
        $("#dialog1").dialog({modal:true});
    });
});
```

But my issue is that when i load the page,echo gets executed and thus displays on screen. But,when I click on the button,the modal dialog does its work fine and the text on the page displayed initially vanishes.

How can i make the php code visible only when modal dialog appears and not before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a CSS to hide your div.

```
<div id="dialog1" title="Some title" style="display:none">
```

Comment: If i set display:none,will the div display be set to block when the modal dialog shows.If that happens,i will have problems later as it will interfere with future interactions on the page.

Comment: If you set display:none the div will hide in normal page body and it will show in dialog.